# Wordpress subdomain integrated with existing website rewrites urls

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I integrated WordPress into my existing PHP website, inside a new folder called "articole". I also created my own theme, as a twentytwelve child theme. And I added in an existing page the wordpress code to show posts for a specific category. 
I added in this page this line:

```
<?php
require('articole/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

and then I do the thing that I do also in my index page of my theme:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=7&category_name=blabla'); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
(...)
```

This page has a name like foo_bar.php, and I have a .htaccess file that rewrites it to foo-bar/ . So all my links are towards foo-bar/ .

The problem is that when I click on a link for foo-bar/ from my index.php, it goes to articole/ (the folder where I have wordpress). It doesn't go to foo-bar/ . If I specify in the url foo_bar.php (or foo-bar/), it goes to my page successfully.

What's the matter here? Why does my "clean" link go to my wordpress blog? I should mention that I also have other pages, that don't contain wordpress code, and that are mod_rewrite (bla_foo_bar.php is re-written to bla-foo-bar/), and work. Only my page that contains WordPress code is messed up.

EDIT:

I changed my link from index.php, from foo-bar/ to foo_bar.php. Same thing happens, I get redirected to my wordpress blog...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was a weird thing. If I had a post called "Foo bar", the page example.com/foo-bar worked. If I deleted the post, the page didn't work anymore. So my "solution" was to add articles that were named like my URLs... and hide them somewhere.